# want to use another df for errorbars in R with barplot

Tags: r, plot

I have these two df.

```
x;

     experiment expression
1    HC         50
2    LC         4
3    HR         10
4    LR         2

y;
 HC_conf_lo HC_conf_hi LC_conf_lo LC_conf_hi    HR_conf_lo HR_conf_hi LR_conf_lo LR_conf_hi
1             63.3293             109.925            2.33971            5.26642              8.8504             16.7707           0.124013           0.434046
```

I want to use df:y to plot low and high conf. points. Output should be a barplot with errorbars. Can someone show me using lines in the basic package how to do this?

Comment: Are the values in y conf.intervals?

Comment: For the future, please use dput to share your data, use this post as a guideline stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @ infominer, This data is made up, thus I dont think I can use dput. Also y is conf. intervals

Comment: even is data is made up, dput makes it easier for others to quickly use it to re-create data in their environment and solve problems. Avoids the use of copy, paste or in some cases copy paste into text files then load data. Hence the suggestion for dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So don't know if your data is valid. Assuming the confidence intervals are valid.
Here's what you can do to get error bars in your data

```
#First reading in your data
x<-read.table("x.txt", header=T)
y<=read.table("y.txt", header =T)
#reshaping y to merge it with x
y.wide <-data.frame(matrix(t(y),ncol=2,byrow=T)) #Transpose Y, 
#matrix with 2 cols, byrow,
#so we get the lo and hi values in one row

names(y.wide)<-c("lo","hi") #name the columns in y.wide
#Make a data.frame of x and y.wide
xy.df <-data.frame(x,y.wide) # this will be used for plotting the error bars
#make a matrix for using with barplot (barplot takes only matrix or table)
xy<-as.matrix(cbind(expression=x$expression,y.wide))
rownames(xy)<-x$experiment #rownames, so barplot can label the bars
#Get ylimts for barplot
ylimits <-range(range(xy$expression), range(xy$lo), range(xy$hi))
barx <-barplot(xy[,1],ylim=c(0,ylimits[2])) #get the x co-ords of the bars
barplot(xy[,1],ylim=c(0,ylimits[2]),main = "barplot of Expression with ? bars")
# ? as don't know if it's C.I, or what
with(xy.df, arrows(barx,expression,barx,lo,angle=90, code=1,length=0.1))
with(xy.df, arrows(barx,expression,barx,hi,angle=90, code=1,length=0.1))
```

Resultant Plot
[image]

But it doesn't look right, This is because your expression values don't fall between the lo and hi values.

With the hack below,

```
barplot(xy[,1],ylim=c(0,ylimits[2]),main = "barplot of Expression with ? bars")
with(xy.df, arrows(barx,lo,barx,hi,angle=90, code=2,length=0.1))
with(xy.df, arrows(barx,hi,barx,lo,angle=90, code=2,length=0.1))
```

The resultant plot [image]

So look at the both `arrows` call carefully, and you will see how I achieved it.
***I would recommend double checking your calculations though.***

And this is far easier with ggplot2. Look at this page for examples and code
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html

Comment: @ informer this is what I want. My cal. would be wrong. I quickly made up some data. This is very helpful. Thanks